# How to save JWT token recieved from auth0 login securely (nodejs express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, auth0

I am new to Auth0 and trying to implement it in my regular express web application. I need to protect/validate the user before they access some of my endpoints. My understanding is that i can do this with the JWT that is returned from the login callback. I have gotten that far, but when I login, it redirects, and I'm unsure of how to pass in the access token/store it securely on the client side.

this is what my callback endpoint looks like after logging in. It returns the authorization code but I am lost from here.

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant

I return this on login:

/callback?code=oi9-ZTieXo0hYL6A&state=sMJAUK4QVs7jziJ7lXvwmGKF

```
// Perform the final stage of authentication and redirect to previously requested URL or '/user'
router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {     
  passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      const returnTo = req.session.returnTo;
      delete req.session.returnTo;  
        res.redirect('/user);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

where do i go from here?

Comment: What about storing the token by using JS sessionstorage? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Comment: if that is the safe way to go, then i'm all for it. how do i both redirect and return this code (its req.url)? I cant send it in a message if i have to redirect i dont think

Comment: once you have it you append it in the header of each protected http requests.

Comment: yes, but how do I get it to the client? do i just append the token in the url? so res.redirect '/user' + req.token ?

Comment: You could use a 'http-only' cookie; add the 'secure' flag for additionaly security. The `http-only` flag prevents the browser from exposing the cookie to frontend JS, and the secure flag makes the browser transport it via encrypted connection (over HTTPS). You can then unpack the cookie and retrieve the token for verification in your verification function. Read more [here](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-cookies-httponly-secure-flags/#gref)

Answer (score 2):

Auth0 does not recommend storing tokens in browser storage (session/local storage). For client side applications, tokens should be short lived and renewed when necessary via silent authentication (renewed via a cookie session with the auth server in a hidded iframe).

This is outlined here:
https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

If you have a backend, then handle the tokens there, if you are using a SPA + API then use the strategy outlined in the link.